# Serverless - can not read file from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have 2 Lambda functions written in NodeJS and with Serverless Framework
IAM role for those functions allows to put and get object:

```
iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "s3:ListBucket"
        - "s3:GetObject"
        - "s3:PutObject"
        - "s3:GetBucketNotification"
        - "s3:PutBucketNotification"
      Resource:
        - Fn::Join: [
            "", [
              "arn:aws:s3:::",
              {
                "Ref": "DataBucket"
              },
              "/*"
            ]
          ]
        - Fn::Join: [
            "", [
              "arn:aws:s3:::",
              {
                "Ref": "DataBucket"
              },
            ]
          ]
```

One function is placing the file to S3 and works correctly and the next second function is invoked (via S3 event) and is not able to read this file because of Access Denied.

It was working correctly until I changed dataBucketName resource name:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    DataBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:custom.dataBucketName}
```

Can someone provide me a hint where the problem could be and how to start debugging it?

Comment: FYI it would be simpler to avoid using the complex, multi-line Fn::Join statements and simply go with "arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.dataBucketName}/*"

Answer (score 1):

This is not a fix for your problem, but to simplify and correct minor issues with your IAM role:

```
iamRoleStatements:
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
  - s3:ListBucket
  - s3:GetBucketNotification
  - s3:PutBucketNotification
  Resource: arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.dataBucketName}
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
  - s3:GetObject
  - s3:PutObject
  Resource: arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.dataBucketName}/*
```